# Segmentation Fault issue in binary search tree

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I have to create a binary search tree for an assignment that sorts strings. I ran debug mode and found where the issue for the segmentation fault is but I have no idea what the issue is or how to fix it. I get

> #0  0x0000000000400969 in Insert (node=0x7fffffffe008, data=0x7fffffffe010 "run\n", c_flag=0) at testbst.c:38
>
> #1  0x0000000000400df8 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe188) at testbst.c:156"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct treeNode
{
    char *data;
    int count;
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;

} treeNode;


void Insert(treeNode** node,char* data,int c_flag)
{
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        treeNode *temp;
        temp = (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
        temp -> data = data;
        printf("%sdata", data);
        printf("\n%stemp", temp -> data);
        temp -> left = NULL;
        temp -> right = NULL;
        *node = temp;
        return;
    }
    
    if(c_flag == 1)
    {
        if(caseCompare((*node)->data, data) == 1)
            Insert(&(*node)->left, data, c_flag);
        if(caseCompare((*node)->data, data) == -1)
            Insert(&(*node)->right, data, c_flag);
        else
            (*node)->count++;
    }
    
    else if(compare((*node)->data, data) == 1)
        Insert(&(*node)->left, data, c_flag);
    if(compare((*node)->data, data) == -1)
        Insert(&(*node)->right, data, c_flag);
    else
        (*node)->count++;
}

void PrintInorder(treeNode *node)
{
    if(node==NULL)
    {
            return;
    }
    PrintInorder(node->left);
    printf("%d ",node->data);
    PrintInorder(node->right);
}

void DeletePostorder(treeNode *node)
{
    if(node != NULL)
    {
        DeletePostorder(node->left);
        DeletePostorder(node->right);
        if(node->left!=NULL)
            free(node->left);
        if(node->right != NULL)
            free(node->right);
        free(node);
    }
}

int compare(char* string1, char* string2)
{
   int str1 = strlen(string1);
   int str2 = strlen(string2);
   int bigger;
   int i = 0;

   if(str1 > str2)
        bigger = str1;
   if(str1 < str2)
        bigger = str2;
   for(i = 0; i < bigger; i++)
{
    if(tolower(string1[i]) > tolower(string1[i]))
        return 1; //returns 1 if string 1 is farther letter
    if(tolower(string1[i]) < tolower(string2[i]))
        return -1; //returns -1 if string 1 letter is behind
}
return 0; //returns 0 if same words
}

int caseCompare(char* string1, char* string2)
{
  int str1 = strlen(string1);
  int str2 = strlen(string2);
  int bigger;
  int i = 0;

  if(str1 > str2)
    bigger = str1;
  if(str1 < str2)
    bigger = str2;
for(i = 0; i < bigger; i++)
{
    if(string1[i] > string1[i])
        return 1; //returns 1 if string 1 is farther letter
    if(string1[i] < string2[i])
        return -1; //returns -1 if string 1 letter is behind
}
return 0; //returns 0 if same words
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
extern char *optarg;
extern int optind;
FILE* infile = stdin;
FILE* outfile = stdout;
char string[100];
treeNode* tree = NULL;
int cflag = 0, oflag = 0, c, err;
static char usage[] = "usage: %s [-c] [-o output_file_name] [input_file_filename]\n";

while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "co:")) != -1)
    switch (c) 
    {
        case 'c':
            cflag  = 1;
            break;
        case 'o':
            oflag = 1;
            outfile = fopen(optarg, "w");
            break; 
        case '?':
            err = 1;
            printf("%s\n", usage);
            break;
    }
    
if((argc - optind) > 1)
{
    printf("Input Incorrect \n%s\n", usage);
    exit(0);
}

if(argv[optind] != NULL)
    if((infile = fopen(argv[optind], "r")) == NULL) 
    {
        printf("File \"%s\" does not exist\nType in your sentences\n", argv[optind]);
        infile = stdin;
    }

while(fgets(string, sizeof(string), infile) != NULL && string[0] != '\n')
{   
    printf("%s", string);
    Insert(&tree, string, cflag);
}
PrintInorder(tree);
DeletePostOrder(tree);

}
```

Comment: `if(node==NULL)`. After that block, the function derferences `node`. Where do you set `node`?

Comment: 1) `if(node==NULL){ .... *node = temp; return;}` 2) `Insert(&tree, string, cflag);` this insert using same buffer(`string`). 3) `free(tree);` Free'd only root.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I changed and initialized temp to node. I don't understand what you meant by #2, and i forgot to use my method to free the tree recursively but i added that in. I still get a segmentation fault, but it printed the first line of the string from a file. Ima edit the code to show

Comment: `temp -> data = data;` That does not make a copy of the data. It means *all* your nodes are pointing to the *same* `string` buffer. Which won't crash in itself but will result in wrong data. What might lead to a crash is this: `if(str1 > str2)` and `if(str1 < str2)`. No `==` case. Which means that `bigger` is not set and has a garbage value when the two strings have equal length (which is always the case for you due to the first bug).

Comment: 4) `string1[i] > string1[i]` typo as `string1[i] > string2[i]` (`compare` same typo too)

Comment: 5) put prototype before use function.

Comment: 6) Add `temp->count = 1;`

Comment: @kaylum how would i make it so each node gets a unique value for data? i also fixed the == case.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i fixed the string comparison issues and added the count but it still gives me a segmentation fault

Comment: `temp->data = strdup(data);`. That allocates new memory and makes a copy of the string. Be sure to `free` the node `data` when cleaning up.

Comment: @kaylum i added that but i'm still getting a segmentation fault when inserting, i'm not really sure where the issue is

Comment: Yeah, when there are bugs there tend to be more than one bug. Unfortunately we can't debug it all for you. Best if you learn ways to debug more effectively - that will more than pay for itself in the long run.

Comment: 7) `DeletePostOrder` typo as `DeletePostorder`

Comment: 9) `printf("%d ",node->data);` --> `printf("%s", node->data);`

Comment: 8)at `Insert`  `if(node==NULL)` --> `if(*node==NULL)`